# Stringformat PlaceHolder with Split for delimited string

Tags: javascript, string

Using js function in
[JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
    String.prototype.format = function () {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
              ? args[number]
              : match
            ;
        });
    };
}
```

Trying to pass delimited fields as a parameter to this function argument. using split to create array and pass it as argument but does not seem to work

```
    var str =" this is a {0} test in {1}";
 var args = "StringFormat|Javascript";
 var return = str.format(args.split("|"));
```

> **actual: this is a StringFormat|Javascript test in {1}**
>
> **expected: this is a StringFormat test in Javascript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `.format()` is not looking for an array of strings, just a string. So this is how you should be calling `.format()` for dynamic arrays per Paolo's suggestion  :

```
var str =" this is a {0} test in {1}";
var args = "StringFormat|Javascript".split("|");
var return = str.format.apply(str, args);
```

Comment: but my args will have dynamic number of pipes. its not fixed.

Comment: [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) would be a better choice. Something like: `str.format.apply(str, args)`

Comment: @JustinHomes Paolo is correct, that is how you should call it if it is dynamic.